# Why $\operatorname{rank} AB≠\operatorname{rank} BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let A,B be two square matrices, say of size n, then why $\operatorname{rank} AB≠\operatorname{rank} BA$? Just need valid reasoning.I just know that above questions has answer 'No'.

Comment: Well, you can simply try to fin a counterexample to this statement. For example, can you find two square matrices such that $AB=0$ but $BA\neq 0$?

Comment: Yes, the two-by-two case already provides examples...

Comment: Just to add a way to think about why this won't be true: we can think of $A$ and $B$ as linear operators $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$, and the products $AB$ and $BA$ are composition. In general, the order of this composition for functions will matter, and in particular the image of $AB$ can be (quite) different from the image of $BA$.

Comment: Note that it is not the case that the ranks are *always* different. Rather, the statement is that the ranks are not always equal: sometimes they are the same, but they need not be the same. Compare with the fact that $AB$ is singular if and only if $AB$ is singular (so $\mathrm{rank}(AB)=n$ *does* imply $\mathrm{rank}(BA)=n$).

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness sake, I will provide an example of $A$ and $B$ such that $AB = 0$ but $BA\neq 0$, as suggested by @richrow in the comments above:

For $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, we have $AB = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ but $BA = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.